# How to customize the sorting rule of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have this code:

```
this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["pubDate"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

but the "pubDate" looks like:

```
Wed, 20 Nov 2019 14:17:33 GMT
```

So the sort of "pubDate" would be wrong

I can use Regex and Enum to make a new string like "2019/11/20 14:17:33"

But how to apply my own sorting rule?

Comment: Did you try `dataGridView1.Columns["pubDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = {put the datetime format which is being returned here}` ?

If the column is in datetime format, it will sort correctly.

Comment: If the column data is an actual date with that display format, it should sort fine.  If not, use date datatypes for dates

Comment: @thebrownkid I try "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss GMT" but the result is still alphabetical order

Comment: @DaveG Is the date which is being passed into that column in a string or a datetime format?

Comment: @thebrownkid string format, it is from a xml file

Comment: @DaveG Well that's the problem, as it is in string format it is sorting alphabetically. You need convert it into a datetime format for correct results.